# Iterate Over Multiple Filenames in Relative Path

Tags: python, filepath

I'm trying to iterate over all .txt filenames that are located in a relative path. *(On my Mac I can't get this to work without the relative path even though the .py file is located in the same directory as the .txt files)* I've used the following:

```
import os
path_str = "Chapter 10_Files_Exceptions/*.txt"
```

When I iterate over each filename in a list called filenames....

```
filenames = ['Chapter 10_Files_Exceptions/alice.txt', 'Chapter 10_Files_Exceptions/siddhartha.txt', 
            'Chapter 10_Files_Exceptions/moby_dick.txt', 'Chapter 10_Files_Exceptions/little_women.txt'
            ]

for filename in filenames:
    count_words(filename)
```

I get this result...

```
*.txt has 29465 within it.
*.txt has 42172 within it.
*.txt has 215830 within it.
*.txt has 189079 within it.
```

**How can I perform the this and get each filename to appear instead of *.txt?**

```
import os
path_str = "Chapter 10_Files_Exceptions/*.txt"

def count_words(filename):
    """Count the approximate number of words in a file."""
    try:
        with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
            contents = f.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"{os.path.basename(path_str).capitalize()} is not located in your current working directory.")
    else:
        words = contents.split()
        num_words = len(words)
        print(f"{os.path.basename(path_str).capitalize()} has {num_words} within it.")

filenames = ['Chapter 10_Files_Exceptions/alice.txt', 'Chapter 10_Files_Exceptions/siddhartha.txt', 
            'Chapter 10_Files_Exceptions/moby_dick.txt', 'Chapter 10_Files_Exceptions/little_women.txt'
            ]

for filename in filenames:
    count_words(filename)
```

Comment: If already have filename as local variable in function why not use filename instread of path_str?

Comment: @CodeMonkey I need to be able to strip off the directory path to just be left with the basename. I couldn't find another way to do that.

Comment: Use Path(filename).name to strip path from the filename.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Thank you! I looked at the pathlib but got a bit confused on how to incorporate it into the function body. Thank you for the additional insight on the stem method as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Path(filename).name` to strip path from the filename. See [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name).

```
from pathlib import Path

def count_words(filename):
   name = Path(filename).name.capitalize()
   ...
   else:
        words = contents.split()
        num_words = len(words)
        print(f"{name} has {num_words} within it.")
```

**Output:**

```
Alice.txt has 29465 within it.
Siddhartha.txt has 42172 within it.
Moby_dick.txt has 215830 within it.
Little_women.txt has 189079 within it.
```

If you want the basename w/o .txt extension then use Path.stem(); e.g. path/Alice.txt => Alice.

```
name = Path(filename).stem.capitalize()
```